# How to execute multiple test fragments through a single Thread Group in JMeter script

Tags: controller, jmeter, fragment

I have a test plan in which i am using 5 Test Fragments given below and using a single Thread Group:

- Test Fragment A
- Test Fragment B
- Test Fragment C
- Test Fragment D
- Test Fragment E

If i use 5 Module controllers i.e one for each test fragment , my test would run for all 5 test fragments.

Is there any functionality which helps me to specify which Fragment i want to execute through command line.

For eg: For Test 1 I want to execute only TF A & TF B and For Test 2 i need TF C, TF D & TF E.

How can i achieve this through any controller in the script or commandline.

Answer (score 0):

Go for [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-weighted-switch-controller-the-ultimate-guide) where you can specify the "weight" of each of its children, this way you can easily orchestrate the choice of the Module Controllers and frequency of their execution.

[image]

Weighted Switch Controller can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]